# Receive messages asynchronously and send synchronously using Telethon

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm having trouble with the code because when I use `time.sleep` The program sleeps completely without being able to receive the messages and when I use `asyncio.sleep()` the program never sleeps but does receive messages.

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
lstDatas = [52, 58, 995, 477, 1447, 885, 6697, 1845, 1002]

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=[botRand1mmm])
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        client.send_message(entity='botRand0mmm',event.message)

    for m in lstDatas:
        ships = client.forward_messages(from_peer='botRand0mmm', entity='botRand1mmm', messages=m, background=True)
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
        asyncio.sleep(2)
   client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I have tried to mix different methods of the async libraries but the part of the message forwarding never sleeps

Answer (score 0):

`telethon.sync` is a hack to not need to `await` methods from the `TelegramClient`, but `asyncio.sleep` is unaffected. The easiest solution is to get rid of the `.sync` hack:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
lstDatas = [52, 58, 995, 477, 1447, 885, 6697, 1845, 1002]

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=[botRand1mmm]))
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            await client.send_message(entity='botRand0mmm',event.message)

        for m in lstDatas:
            ships = await client.forward_messages(from_peer='botRand0mmm', entity='botRand1mmm', messages=m, background=True)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
   await client.run_until_disconnected()

asyncio.run(main())
```